# How to use ActiveSheet.[Cells(),Cells()]

Tags: excel, vba

This is to select random values from unique data validation lists by column starting in column D.  Once my criteria is met I want to move to the next column.  The problem with what I have lies in the line

"For Each iCell In ActiveSheet.[Cells(4,r):Cells(78,r)]"

It works for column D when I use "ActiveSheet.[D4:D78]" but not as it currently is.

Please help.

```
Sub build()
Dim r As Long
r = 4
Do While r < 36
    Do While Cells(81, r) < 4 And Cells(82, r) < 4 And Cells(83, r) < 9 And Cells(84, r) < 9
        Dim iCell As Range
        Randomize
        For Each iCell In ActiveSheet.[Cells(4,r):Cells(78,r)]
            iCell.Value = Range(iCell.Validation.Formula1).Cells(Int(Range(iCell.Validation.Formula1).Count * Rnd + 1))
        Next
    Loop
    r = r + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each iCell In ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(4,r),ActiveSheet.Cells(78,r))` or since you are only looking at the active sheet `Range(Cells(4,r),Cells(78,r))`

Comment: Cells(81, r) < 4.... how can these statements be true? are you saying the value of the cell? cells.value <4?

Comment: @gemmo the default of Cells() is `.Value`, Though my OCD requires I put it, it is not needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great!